# Reference to JSON element within array using variable not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am having problems to resolve this, though I'm using this mechanism all over my project.

The code has a JSON array assigned to a variable `p_JSON_Array`. I'm trying to extract a value but I'm getting `undefined`.

Here are the printout commands:

```
console.log("JSON.strigify(p_JSON_Array[0])                : " + JSON.stringify(p_JSON_Array[0],' ',4  ) );
console.log("llll_ttt                                      : " + llll_ttt  ) ;
console.log("p_JSON_Array[0][llll_ttt]                     : " + p_JSON_Array[0][llll_ttt]  ) ;
```

and the results:

```
JSON.strigify(p_JSON_Array[0])                : {
        "Sampling_ID": "1500327",
        "Parameter_Name": "AG",
        "Sequence_Number": "0",
        "Parameter_Value": "",
        "Required_Completion_Date": "Jan1190012:00AM",
        "Field_Status": "1",
        "No_Measurement_Code": "0",
        "Anomaly_Type": "0",
        "Measuring_Method_Code": "115",
        "Minimal_Quantitative_Threshold": "0.500",
        "General_Comment": "",
        "Update_Reason_Code": "0",
        "Feasibility_Min": "0.500",
        "Feasibility_Max": "999999.000",
        "Applicable_Methods_List": "21,115"
    }

llll_ttt                                      : Parmameter_Name
p_JSON_Array[0][llll_ttt]                     : undefined
```

So, as it can be seen above, the array element `p_JSON_Array[0]` exists and contains a field named `Parameter_Name`. The variable `llll_ttt` evaluates to `Parameter_Name`.

Still, `p_JSON_Array[0][llll_ttt]` is undefined.

What am I missing here!?!?!?

Comment: this is a json object

Comment: @rahulmr [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Parmameter_Name" - you have a misspell here.

Comment: Please flag the question as "should be closed/simple typo".

Comment: Thank you @nikish. I could had spent hours looking for the error.